# React Async Function wrapped in a UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am confused on how an async function works.

The console.log returns an error because the data.rates does not exist yet. But I thought because the useEffect function is async anything under it would be called after the async is over.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        "https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest"
      );
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);

  console.log(data.rates); <-- Error data.rates does not exist
  return <div>{!data ? "Loading..." : "Hello"}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Initially your state `data` is undefined so you're getting the error when logging it.

Comment: Once the state is updated you should see the correct value logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is actually correct, useEffect in this scenario will run when the Component is *mounted* that means `console.log` will be called twice--first with initial value (which is undefined), second is after useEffect performed the side-effect when data is actually set (setData) after the request is fulfilled. You would typically provide a "loading" state while data is stale.

```js
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.get(
        "https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest"
      );
      setLoading(false);
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Fetching data...</div>

  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like none of the answers actually answer the question.

`useEffect` doesn't stop the flow of execution, it doesn't matter what you're doing inside the callback passed to it. So the `console.log(data.rates)` gets executed and then once the component is mounted the callback passed to `useEffect` is executed. Since the state is being changed in the callback(`setData(result.data)`) this triggers a re-render and this time you should see that the correct value is logged without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (I've kind of created a workaround)

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(()=>{
        const setObtainedData=async()=>{
            const result = await axios.get("https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest");
            setData(result.data);
        };
        setObtainedData();
    },[]);

    if(data){
        console.log(data.rates);
    }
    return <div>{!data ? "Loading..." : "Hello"}</div>;
};
```